# Routing traffic from Windows to device on debian linux

Tags: linux, networking

I'm wondering if I have all the networking set up correctly for my situation on the debian computer.

I have set up a pelora CL-TEN frame grabber and JAI camera on my Debian 9.5 (stretch) server.

The frame grabber is connected via ethernet to an Intel NIC which debian has identified as enp216s0f1.

The debian server is connected to a netgear switch sitting next to the server and the switch is connected to the corporate network.  Debian identified that interface as eno3 and it uses dhcp to get the ip address.

My goal is to get the camera working from Debian so the pleora player can capture devices when running on the debian computer and also when the pleora player is running on my windows computer.

To achieve these goals I bridged the two interfaces as:

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces.d/br0

```
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        bridge_ports eno3 enp216s0f1
```

This results in `ip addr show` like:

```
...
5: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether ac:1f:6b:0e:69:0a brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: enp216s0f1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master br0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e2:ba:d9:3d:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
...
8: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:e2:ba:d9:3d:05 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.90.3.215/20 brd 10.90.15.255 scope global br0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::92e2:baff:fed9:3d05/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I run the ebus player software on the debian server and I can connect to the camera.  In the player software you assign an IP address which I assigned as 10.90.3.216.

From the debian command line I can successfully ping 10.90.3.216.  So, it's all working on debian fine.

My windows 10 computer is connected to the netgear switch sitting next to the debian server.  The ip address of the windows computer is 10.90.2.48.

From the windows computer, I can ping 10.90.3.215 successfully.  But, I cannot ping 10.90.3.216. And tracert can't find a path.

Do you have any suggestions on what else I can do to get this working properly?

Comment: Using tcpdump, it looks like the ping 10.90.3.216 is getting through 10.90.3.215 (ip for debian server).  But, it's not getting routed to 10.90.3.216 (ip for camera).  Ping 10.90.3.216 works fine when run on the debian server.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is related to iptables.  I had added the following entries to /etc/sysctl.conf, but they hadn't taken effect (even though I had rebooted several times).  I ran sysctl -p and it started working.

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 0
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 0
```